# Adding an image to AnyGantt datagrid column

Tags: gantt-chart, anychart

Is it possible to add an image next to the name of the resource in a datagrid column of anychart.ganttResource() view?

I tried to use a customFormatter with useHtml(true), but looks like it only formats the text, no luck inserting an `<img>` tag in there.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mendi,
As of September 2017, AnyGantt 7.14.3 doesn't provide images in datagrid. Method useHTML() influences only on text settings. You may learn more about useHTML() method here: https://docs.anychart.com/7.14.3/Appearance_Settings/Text_Settings#html